# django-paypal setup

Tags: python, django, paypal

Has anyone setup django-paypal? Here is the link to it [here](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal)?

I have "myproject" setup, and my folder sturecture looks like this:

myproject > paypal > (stdandard and pro folders)

to my settins.py file I added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'myproject.paypal.standard',
    'myproject.paypal.pro',
)
```

in my url's file for my account app I added:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('myproject.account.views',
    (r'^payment-url/$', 'buy_my_item'),                   
)
```

and in my account view I added:

```
from myproject.paypal.pro.views import PayPalPro
from myproject.paypal.pro.forms import PaymentForm, ConfirmForm

def buy_my_item(request):
    item = {'amt':"10.00",              # amount to charge for item
            'inv':"1111",         # unique tracking variable paypal
            'custom':"2222",       # custom tracking variable for you
            'cancelurl':"http://127.0.0.1:8000/",   # Express checkout cancel url
            'returnurl':"http://127.0.0.1:8000/"}   # Express checkout return url

    kw = {'item':'item',                            # what you're selling
           'payment_template': 'pro/payment.html',          # template to use for payment form
           'confirm_template': ConfirmForm,  # form class to use for Express checkout confirmation
           'payment_form_cls': PaymentForm,  # form class to use for payment
           'success_url': '/success',               # where to redirect after successful payment
           }

    ppp = PayPalPro(**kw)
    return ppp(request)
```

--- EDIT ---------
Then, I added the pro and standard template folders to my projects template folder.

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/payment-url/ and submit the form...

I get a ValueError : "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Traceback:

```
File "...\accounts\views.py" in buy_my_item
  655.     return ppp(request)
File "...\paypal\pro\views.py" in __call__
  115.                 return self.validate_payment_form()
File "...\paypal\pro\views.py" in validate_payment_form
  133.             success = form.process(self.request, self.item)
File "...\paypal\pro\forms.py" in process
```

35. params.update(item)

Comment: Updated the tags for a wider audience

Comment: kw = {"item": ____ITEM_____ ...} Your passing the string "item" instead of the `item` dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code...

```
  'payment_form_cls': 'payment_form_cls',  # form class to use for payment
```

This must be a Form object that's used for validation.

```
   'payment_form_cls': MyValidationForm,  # form class to use for payment
```

---

**Edit**

http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal/tree/master

Your request is supposed to include a notify-url, return-url and cancel-return.  All three url's YOU provide to Paypal.

Paypal will send messages to these URL's.

Since Paypal will send messages to these URL's, YOU must put them in your urls.py.  You must write view functions for these three urls'.  These urls will have your paypal responses sent to them.

Comment: It doesn't use anything by default.  You provided a string, not a Form object.  That's why you got the "str not callable" error.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now.  Do you know where I can find some more information on how to setup his third point: "Add the IPN endpoints to your urls.py to receive callbacks from PayPal." How do you read the information Paypal send back? Thanks agian for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal django Integration](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/11/using-paypal-with-django/) post should help you.