# Django payment processing

Tags: python, django

Can anyone suggest any good payment processing libraries for python/django?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757809/django-paypal-setup

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most developed Django solution is [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/svn/) with support for Authorize.Net, TrustCommerce, CyberSource, PayPal, Google Checkout, and Protx.

The new kid on the Django block is [django-lfs](http://code.google.com/p/django-lfs/) which looks like only support for PayPal at the moment, and even that may not be complete.

For general Python the main player is [getpaid](http://code.google.com/p/getpaid/)

Comment: Payment processors supported by getpaid listed here: http://code.google.com/p/getpaid/wiki/PaymentProcessors

Comment: a New new kid is django-store by the same people of django-cms, there is no release but there is a good code on his git repo

Comment: The link for Satchmo is broken…

Answer (score 3):

There is [Django payments application called Mamona](http://github.com/emesik/mamona) which currently supports only PayPal. It can be used with any existing application without changing it's code. Basically, it can use **any exiting model** as order.

Comment: thanks, that looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can find some usefull code hints/modules looking at Satchmo: 
[Satchmo Homepage](http://www.satchmoproject.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Django paypal is very cool. I've used in on couple of my projects. It is relatively easy to integrate with an existing website. 
Satchmo is good, if you want a full internet store, but if you want to sell just couple items from your website, which is devoted to something else, you will find Satchmo to be very heavy (a lot of dependencies to install, really complicates your admin).

Comment: +1 I've been experimenting with Django PayPal (http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal/tree) lately and I recommend it if you just need a payment library and are using PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at https://github.com/bkeating/python-payflowpro/ which isn't django-specific but works nicely with it or in plain ole python.

Answer (score 0):

I created Paython: https://github.com/abunsen/Paython

Supports a few different processors:

1. Stripe
2. Authorize.net
3. First Data / Linkpoint
4. Innovative Gateway (from intuit)
5. Plugnpay
6. Samurai