# Good solution for Payment Processing in Django

Tags: python, django, payment-processing, django-paypal

I am trying to pick a payment processing solution for my Django app and would like to know of some good general solutions.

The following look rather promising:

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/payment-processing/ (General solution)
https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal (paypal only)

This is a link to a bit dated version of the question: [Django payment proccessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772240/django-payment-proccessing)

### Question:

What is/are some secure and current Django app solutions for payment processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Django-Merchant https://github.com/agiliq/merchant

> Django-Merchant is a django application that enables you to use
>   multiple payment processors from a single API.
>
> **Gateways**
>
> Following gateways are supported:
>
> Authorize.net
>   Paypal
>   Eway
>   Braintree Payments (Server to Server)
>   Stripe
>   Paylane
>   WePay
>   Beanstream
>   Chargebee
>   Global Iris
>
> **Off-Site Processing**
>
> Paypal
>   RBS WorldPay
>   Google Checkout
>   Amazon FPS
>   Braintree Payments (Transparent Redirect)
>   Stripe.js
>   eWAY
>   Authorize.net Direct Post Method
>   Global Iris RealMPI
>
> **Other**
>
> Bitcoin

Comment: The only other one that looks promising is django-payments at https://github.com/mirumee/django-payments which seems to have quite a few backends also. I have not tried either but would like to know if anyone has used both and has a preference and if so why.