# connect website to paypal

Tags: python, django, paypal

Is there a possibility of connecting paypal account to website? Such as facebook connect? I want to make a verification tool which:
1. takes me to paypal website
2. wants me to log in
3. redirects me back to my website and sends some authorization data.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757809/django-paypal-setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paypal has great documentation on how to connect to it, including some SDK's and sample code (I don't see anything in Python, though). See https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

If you follow dcrodjer's link, you'll eventually find a link to a project called django-paypal on github, which might help you, too. (I'd post the link, but my reputation is not high enough yet to post more than one link in an answer).

Other than that library, and the official documentation, I'm not 100% sure what exactly you are trying to do. You don't really connect accounts like you do with Facebook, you mostly do one shot authorizations for purchases or recurring purchases. But check out the documentation, and you should be able to find what you need.

Comment: Thank you for help. I found some sample code in python here: https://www.x.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/2199-102-1-2509/python_nv_authentication.zip.

Comment: I wouldn't endorse the "great" part of your answer's first paragraph, but helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I found sample python code [here](https://www.x.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/2199-102-1-2509/python_nv_authentication.zip). It helped me to integrate my website. Some technical documentation is [here](https://www.paypal-labs.com/files/PayPal_Authentication_Service.pdf). However you may have some problems with testing this service because it is disabled for sandbox accounts. If you want to turn it on you have to make steps described [here](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/authentication?token=HA-QJQ9T5GGUVSV8) in section "Sandbox and Live access".