# django-paypal module for DJango

Tags: python, django

I have to use a Django project that uses **django-paypal**. So when I run the command "python manage.py runserver" it throws "ImportError: No module named paypal.standard" .

My question is how can I install Paypal module as this module does not have any setup.py file. I am using **Bitnami Django Stack for Windows**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from where you've downloaded but [this one](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-paypal/0.1.2) has setup.py
Or you can just copy the `paypal` folder into your site-packages dir.

For further setup you can also check out:

[django-paypal setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757809/django-paypal-setup)